# ¿Cómo hacer un vector con los números de los índices de una condición?

Tags: r, eliminar-duplicados

Tengo un data frame con números duplicados de DNI, cuando yo corro el código:

```
duplicados <-duplicated(df$NRO_DOC)
```

Me aparecen TRUE o FALSE según si son o no duplicados, con el índice correspondiente. Por ejemplo, 1 FALSE 2 FALSE 3 TRUE 4 FALSE. Lo que yo quiero es obtener un vector con todos los números de índice en donde la condición sea TRUE así después puedo armar un data frame aparte con todos los números duplicados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener las filas cuyo `NRO_DOC` este duplicado:

```
df[duplicated(df$NRO_DOC), ]
```

Esto te va a repetir filas, pero si quieres solo los números de documentos repetidos:

```
unique(df$NRO_DOC[duplicated(df$NRO_DOC)])
```

Para obtener todas las filas con un documento duplicado:

```
df[df$NRO_DOC %in% df$NRO_DOC[duplicated(df$NRO_DOC)],]
```

Comment: La primera fórmula me arma un df con los número de DNI duplicados directamente. Yo lo que necesito es tener los índices para armar un df con el original + el duplicado (por ejemplo, si el duplicado es el de la fila 17 yo tendría que armar un df con los número 16 y 17 así me toma ambos). 

La segunda fórmula me muestra los DNI duplicados, eso me puede servir, pero como puedo hacer para crear un data frame? Los asigno a un vector, por ejemplo "numeros", y luego como hago para hacer un data frame con mi base original pero que me tome "numeros" como filtro para la variable NRO_DOC

Comment: Prueba con: `df[df$NRO_DOC %in% duplicated(df$NRO_DOC), ]`

Comment: El último código no me funcionó, me muestra un df vacío. Probé con 

numeros <- unique(sin_dups$NRO_DOC[duplicated(sin_dups$NRO_DOC)])

Pero no sé como hacer para que estos números de DNI que tengo en un vector sean los que me muestre del df

Comment: Mala mía, así: `df[df$NRO_DOC %in% df$NRO_DOC[duplicated(df$NRO_DOC)],]`

Comment: Gracias patricio, sos todo lo que está bien